# How to structure a react-redux reducer with Typescript to handle different kinds of payloads?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

So, I'm trying to build a Todo App with react, redux and typescript. There are going to be some todo pages and each page will involve todos.

Below are the necessary types and the Todos state.

```js
export type Todo = {
  name: string;
  due: Date;
  color: string;
  pageId: string;
};

export type TodosByPageId = {
  [page: string]: Todo[];
}

export type TodosState = {
  byPageId: TodosByPageId;
  curPageId: string;
};
```

After defining my constants and actions I export below given actions for the reducer:

```js
export type TodosAction = SetTodos | AddTodo | DeleteTodo | UpdateTodo | SetTodoPageId;
```

Basically

- AddTodo, DeleteTodo and UpdateTodo takes a todo and payload is a Todo
- SetTodos takes Todo[] and payload is Todo[]
- SetTodoPageId takes string and payload is string

Then I started defining the todosReducer:

```js
const initalState: TodosState = {
  byPageId: {},
  curPageId: '',
}

const todosReducer = (state: TodosState, action: TodosAction): TodosState => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case Constants.ADD_TODO:
      return state; // TODO
    case Constants.DELETE_TODO:
      return state; // TODO
    case Constants.SET_TODOS:
      return state; // TODO
    case Constants.SET_TODO_PAGE_ID:
      return { ...state, curPageId: action.payload };
    case Constants.UPDATE_TODO:
      return state; // TODO
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

At the line I handled `SET_TODO_PAGE_ID` gave me the error

```
Type 'string | Todo | Todo[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  Type 'Todo' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

which makes sense. Typecasting in each case didn't seem right, so I wanted to ask what would be a better design for these kinds of situations?

By the way, I know redux toolkit is the suggested way, but I'm just trying to learn both styles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a Redux maintainer.

As you noted: the first answer here is that **[you *should* be using Redux Toolkit](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#use-redux-toolkit-for-writing-redux-logic)**.  We specifically recommend *against* trying to write reducers and actions by hand today.  We do have a ["Redux Fundamentals" tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-1-overview) in our docs that shows how to hand-write Redux code, but *only* so that you understand the basic mechanics.  For any actual app, you *should* be using RTK.

The second observation is that [you *should not* be writing TS action type unions](https://redux.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#avoid-action-type-unions) - they don't provide any real benefit, and don't actually represent how the code runs.

Please follow the approach shown in [our Redux TS Quick Start docs page](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/typescript-quick-start) instead.

Comment: Alright, thank you for the answer!